# Moving a file inside the same File System

Tags: filesystems, mv, inode

I am trying to understand what it happens to a file when I move it from a directory to another, **inside the same File System**.

Here is the example I made up.

I have two directories and a file :

- `~/Documents/dir1`
- `~/Documents/dir2`
- `~/Documents/dir1/fileName.txt`

Here I have some details about the file `fileName.txt` (`ls -li`):

```
784088 -rw-r--r-- 1 myUser myUser 0 Oct 25 02:18 fileName.txt
```

Then, I moved the file `fileName.txt` from `dir1` to `dir2` by issuing the following command:

```
~/Documents/dir1$ mv fileName.txt ../dir2
```

and here I have the details about the file `fileName.txt` (`ls -li`) after having issued `mv`:

```
784088 -rw-r--r-- 1 myUser myUser 0 Oct 25 02:22 fileName.txt
```

What I expected was a change of **inode** number, but I was wrong . So, for what I have understood up to now, by moving a file inside the same File System:

- the data block is not touched (that's good to me)
- the inode (that is strange to me)

Can anyone tell me then what it changes in file properties (apart from modification time)?

Thank you in advance, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the same filesystem, `mv`-ing actually uses `rename(2)`. So the inode will remain intact, just the inode is removed from one directory entry and attached to another.

Comment: hi heemayl, I do thank you, really. Your explenation is definitely clear!